# Seat arrangement using Oracle SQL for examination

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I was trying to arrange seat for an examination from the below dataset.

[image]

and the output dataset would be like the below(alternate department student one after another)

[image]

I am unable to get the desire output. Please help me on that. I am using the Oracle 11g express edition.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/510071/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function, create sort order for each department; then select values sorted by that number.

For example:

```
SQL> with test (roll_no, name, department) as
  2    (select  1, 'anik',    'cse' from dual union all
  3     select  2, 'sudipto', 'cse' from dual union all
  4     select  3, 'injamam', 'cse' from dual union all
  5     select  8, 'sajukta', 'ece' from dual union all
  6     select  9, 'gourab',  'ece' from dual union all
  7     select 10, 'soumenn', 'ece' from dual),
  8  inter as
  9    (select roll_no, name, department,
 10       row_number() over (partition by department order by roll_no) rn
 11     from test
 12    )
 13  select roll_no, name, department
 14  from inter
 15  order by rn, department;

   ROLL_NO NAME    DEP
---------- ------- ---
         1 anik    cse
         8 sajukta ece
         2 sudipto cse
         9 gourab  ece
         3 injamam cse
        10 soumenn ece

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want them interleaved.  If so, use `row_number()` in the `order by`:

```
select s.*
from student s
order by row_number() over (partition by "department" order by "roll_no"),
         "department";
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/510071/6) is the SQL Fiddle.

Note:  Don't wrap column names in double quotes.  That means that the case of the identifier matters -- and just makes queries harder to write.

Comment: is there any other general way to do this like a union or somewhat because i think for other databases it might not work

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja - most other RDBMS support analytic functions like this. Even recent versions of MySQL do.